# What puts a limit on lowering $\langle T\rangle$ low avg in heat engines?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

I have a simple question which is: We know that the thermal effeciency in heat engines increases when we lower the average temperature at which heat is rejected. But the problem is that there is always a limit for lowering this temperature. Since the reason behind that is the cooling medium (sink) temperature. But why are we really limited by this cooling medium temperature. Why is it actually limiting the low temperature average . All thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> We know that the thermal efficiency in heat engines increases when we
> lower the average temperature at which heat is rejected.

The thermal efficiency increases when the difference between the temperature where heat is added and heat is rejected is increased.

> But the problem is that there is always a limit for lowering this
> temperature.

The only theoretical lower temperature limit is absolute zero Kelvin.

> But why are we really limited by this cooling medium temperature. Why
> is it actually limiting the low temperature average .

Your efficiency is not limited by the low temperature reservoir. You can increase the efficiency by increasing the temperature of the high temperature reservoir.

Practical considerations limit how low the temperature of the low temperature reservoir can be.  The low temperature for most practical heat engines is atmospheric temperature. To lower the temperature further would require refrigeration work input, which would kind of defeat the whole purpose of lowering the temperature.

To quote from the Wikipedia article on Heat Engines:

*"On Earth, the cold side of any heat engine is limited to being close to the ambient temperature of the environment, or not much lower than 300 Kelvin, so most efforts to improve the thermodynamic efficiencies of various heat engines focus on increasing the temperature of the source, within material limits"*.

Hope this helps.